# Mysql Select statement based on hour, day, month, year

Tags: mysql

I have a table with value look like this

```
id         time_stamp                    value    
1          2013-01-01 00:00:15           10
2          2013-01-01 01:00:15            5
3          2013-01-02 00:00:15           15
4          2013-01-02 01:00:15           20
5          2013-02-01 00:00:15           18
6          2013-02-01 01:00:15           15
7          2013-02-02 00:00:15           5
8          2013-02-02 01:00:15           17
9          2014-01-01 00:00:15           8
10         2014-01-01 01:00:15            5
11         2014-01-02 00:00:15           15
12         2014-01-02 01:00:15           30
13         2014-02-01 00:00:15           18
14         2014-02-01 01:00:15           15
15         2014-02-02 00:00:15           5
16         2014-02-02 01:00:15           17
```

From this table I want to select the first record value and the last record value based on hour, day, month, year
For example I select value based on

Day:

```
id  time_stamp              start_value               end_value
1   2013-01-01              10                         5
2   2013-01-02              15                         20
3   2013-02-01              18                         15

and so on

Month:
id  time_stamp              start_value               end_value
1   2013 jan                10                         20
2   2013 feb                18                         17
3   2014 jan                8                          30
4   2014 feb                18                         17

Year:
id  time_stamp              start_value               end_value
1   2013                    10                         17
2   2014                    8                          17
```

How can I do this?

Comment: select * from table WHERE time_stamp BETWEEN "2012-01-01" AND "2012-02-01" group by day(time_stamp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use mysql's aggregation functions such as the following

```
SELECT 
    t.id, 
    DATE_FORMAT(t.time_stamp, "%Y-%m-%d") AS time_stamp, 
    (SELECT `value` FROM table_name WHERE time_stamp BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(t.time_stamp, "%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00") AND DATE_FORMAT(t.time_stamp, "%Y-%m-%d 23:59:59") ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1) AS start_value,
    (SELECT `value` FROM table_name WHERE time_stamp BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(t.time_stamp, "%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00") AND DATE_FORMAT(t.time_stamp, "%Y-%m-%d 23:59:59") ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1) AS end_value
FROM table_name t 
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(t.time_stamp, "%Y-%m-%d")
```

I've provided extra parameters on the query, to help you by keeping the query flexible :)

Comment: Where's the required `GROUP BY` clause?

Comment: i dont want min & max value. i want only first record value & last record value of hour, day, month and year

Comment: You don't need one when you're using MIN and MAX, that's like asking where's the GROUP BY in a COUNT(*) query...

Comment: So you don't care about the chronological ordering of the time? You want it based on the ID?

Comment: i only care about time_stamp asc, not for id

Comment: I've updated the query to return the start and end values for each day at a time, please understand that I invested a fair amount of work trying to figure this out for you, and I'm hoping that you'll enjoy the customization to get it to work for months / years, it's very close :)

Comment: You're very welcome :) Please feel free to accept the answer, and maybe even upvote it for old times sake :-P

Comment: @user1376389: This may produce what you want. But don't try it with anything but a tiny table. Performance nightmare.